# JOLT to join different properties

Tags: json, jolt

Source JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "metrics": {
      "cost_per_app_install": "0.08",
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "stat_time_day": "2021-06-04 00:00:00",
      "campaign_id": 170011516
    }
  },
  {
    "metrics": {
      "cost_per_app_install": "12.3",
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "stat_time_day": "2021-06-04 00:00:00",
      "campaign_id": 17013
    }
  }
]
```

Expected:

```json
[
  {
    "cost_per_app_install": "0.08",
    "stat_time_day": "2021-06-04 00:00:00",
    "campaign_id": 170011516
  },
  {
    "cost_per_app_install": "12.3",
    "stat_time_day": "2021-06-04 00:00:00",
    "campaign_id": 17013
  }
]
```

JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "metrics": "[&1]",
        "dimensions": "[&1]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to add data from `dimensions` and `metrics` properties as one combined record. But unable with my JOLT config. This config just removes `metrics` and `dimensions` namings. Can I do it only with `shift` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more step to roam the indexes such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": { "*": "[&2].&" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Btw, no need to explicitly list the **key-value** pairs for the current case, just `"*": "[&1]"` should be preferred rather than `"metrics": "[&1]","dimensions": "[&1]"` for the current pairs if it were the case.